# No microphone (one way, out) when first initiating a call with someone (Redmi Note 9S)

Tags: calls, redmi, miui-13

I've been experiencing strange behaviour when making calls with my Redmi Note 9S. Whenever I try to call someone or pickup a call from someone, if it's the first time I've called them in an unknown amount of time (maybe a few hours or so), they aren't able to hear me. I have to end the call, and then redial for them to be able to hear me.

I can hear them without issue, and the problem persists regardless of whether I'm using the built-in mic or headphone speakers.

I'm on MIUI Global 12.5.6 with a prompt to update to MIUI 13, but this update seems to be broken as it fails whether it downloads the update itself or I download it manually and pass the update file into the update manager. It fails for seemingly inconsistent reasons, where either the download fails or it can't install the update. Maybe this could be the problem?